# Parse Facebook login shows always Facebook page "you have already authorized this app"

Tags: facebook, authentication, parse-platform

In my app, I can log into Parse via Facebook. However after the 1st login, further login always show a Facebook page saying "*you have already authorized this app*“, and I have to press OK. This is useless and annoying.
According to the information on the web, this happens now for more than 2 years, and many questions like this have been asked but no solution has been given.

Opening of the Facebook page is apparently done by the statement

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {…
```

Now, Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3 says:

***Check for Existing Tokens***
After you add the button, you should update your view controller to check for an existing token at load. This eliminates an unnecessary app switch to Facebook if someone already granted permissions to your app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
   // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller. 
  }
}
```

But this check is apparently not done in the `PFFacebookUtils` method.
So, is this a Parse problem (why has it not been solved in the last 2 years?), or is there a way to avoid this annoying roundtrip to the Facebook page?
Any help is appreeciated.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But by now the Parse UI is open source, and maybe one could modify it so that the problem disappears. I hope I can look into it soon.

Comment: I just realized that PFFacebookUtils is not (yet?) open source, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that worked for me. Although it still goes to Facebook page if user is logged out and then logged in again...

```
if let accessToken: FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(accessToken, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            println("User logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. There was an error logging in.")
        }
    })
} else {
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")                       
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you do not use the Parse PFLogInViewController for login, but you do it in code, and you still have the problem that I described above. If so, what is the advantage?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I don't think there is any actually. I still haven't found a solution that is acceptable but the last thing I tried was to forget Parse and just go with the Facebook SDK. That is a much better UX but the problem with that is I haven't figured out a good way to create a Parse user from the FB login... Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I would have tried this next, but if you did not have success... Maybe some Parse guy is listening and cares about it...